# How to set property value of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to TextBox.Text?

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I have Linq object which has one field of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. When bound to Gridview this XML is properly displayed as text. However, when I try to edit that row and update Linq object I get error:

Cannot convert value of parameter 'CustomData' from 'System.String' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.

What is the easiest way to enable editing of XML doc as text and returning it back with row update without this error?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
MyTextBox.Text = MyXElement.Value
```

??

Marc